# How can I select one column from an SQL query with the "SHOW" keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I select one column from this SQL query:

```
SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

like this:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

This code worked for me

```
SELECT k.column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
 AND t.table_schema='YOURDATABASE'
 AND t.table_name='YOURTABLE';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to fetch the column name of primary keys, you can use this query which gets the information from the information_schema.statistics table. You can filter the information by schema / table name as well.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE table_schema='schema_name'
AND table_name = 'table_name'
AND index_name='PRIMARY'
ORDER BY seq_in_index;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it return "Column_name" as null

Comment: Are you sure you have a primary key on that table? Can you try the query without the table_schema and table_name filters?